# python regex letter must be followed by another letter

Tags: python, regex

A string consists of letters and numbers but if it contains a 'c' the following letter after the 'c' must be either 'h' or 'k', does anyone know how to write such a regex for Python?

Comment: This sound like a homework assignement, if it is you should tag it with that.

Comment: @DanielFigueroa: the homework tag has been [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Comment: @DSM That's to bad, i liked that tag. :'(

Comment: If it doesn't need to be a regex, and you only want the answer, then `(s.isalnum() and all(s[i+1:i+2] in ('h', 'k') for i, c in enumerate(s) if c == 'c'))` should work equally well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
^(?!.*c(?![hk]))[^\W_]+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       # Start of string
(?!     # Assert that it's not possible to match...
 .*     #  Any string, followed by
 c      #  the letter c
 (?!    #  unless that is followed by
  [hk]  #   h or k
 )      #  (End of inner negative lookahead)
)       # (End of outer negative lookahead).
[^\W_]+ # Match one or more letters or digits.
$       # End of string
```

`[^\W_]` means "Match any character that's matched by `\w`, excluding the `_`".

```
>>> import re
>>> strings = ["test", "check", "tick", "pic", "cow"]
>>> for item in strings:
...     print("{0} is {1}".format(item,
...           "valid" if re.match(r"^(?!.*c(?![hk]))[^\W_]+$", item)
...           else "invalid"))
...
test is valid
check is valid
tick is valid
pic is invalid
cow is invalid
```

Comment: I tried it like this: regex = re.compile("^(?!.*c(?![hk]))[^\W_]+$") regex.match("test") which gets me the result that 'test' contains 'ch' or 'ck' which is obviously not true!?

Comment: @user1606657: Please read the comments to the regex. It matches a string that consists only of letters/digits, unless a c is present that's not part of ch/ck. Which is exactly what you asked for, isn't it?

Comment: No not exactly, every string should be valid if it does not contain a 'c', if it contains a 'c' the 'c' must be followed by either 'h' or 'k' then it is valid too, e.g. 'test'->valid, 'check'->valid, 'tick'->valid, 'cow'->NOTVALID, 'pic'->NOTVALID

Comment: @user1606657: Yes, and that's exactly the result you get from this regex. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `^([^\Wc]*(c[hk])*)*$` also works.  It says the whole string (from `^` to `$`) must consist of repetitions of blocks where each block has any number of non-c characters, `[^\Wc]*`, and any number of `ch` or `ck` pairs, `(c[hk])*` .

For example:
`re.search(r'^([^\Wc]*(c[hk])*)*$', 'checkchek').group()`
gives
'checkchek'

If you don't want to match the empty string, replace the last `*` with a `+`.   Ordinarily, to avoid errors like mentioned in a comment when the input string doesn't match, assign the search result to a variable and test for not none:

```
In [88]: y = re.search(r'^([^\Wc]*(c[hk])*)*$', 'ca')

In [89]: if y:
   ....:     print y.group()
   ....: else:
   ....:     print 'No match'
   ....:     
No match
```

Comment: `re.search(r'^([^\Wc]*(c[hk])*)*$', 'ca').group()` throws an error.

Comment: @btoueg, yes, group() was just used for a simple matching example.  See edit.

Answer (score -1):

The following code detects the presence of "c not followed by h or k" in myinputstring, and if so it prints "problem":

```
import re
if ((re.findall(r'c(?!(h|k))', myinputstring).length)>0):
    print "problem"
```

Comment: @PeterStahl: Well, you could always negate the result of the match. However, it doesn't address the requirement that the string may only contain letters and digits.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Sure, you can negate the result of this regex to get what the OP wants, but how inconvenient is that?

Comment: The question from OP is not clear : what does he want to do in the first place ?

Comment: @PeterStahl: Regexes are designed to match text. Trying to make them *not* match text sometimes requires logical contortions. My regex does do everything the OP wants, but is it readable? Two `if` statements with two simple regexes may be better than one giant regex.